# How to send data in infinite loop from server to client throught python socket.io?

Tags: python-3.x, socket.io

I want to send data (like endless stream) from one vds machine to another. I've read that it's possible to do with python-socket.io. First of all, I try to do it on my laptop (server script runs in one terminal, client - in another). And send numbers from "server" to "client" in infinite loop. I want to get data on client side in real-time. (Server sent "1", client got "1", etc) But, when I run both scripts I see that server is sending data and client gets nothing. Only when I stop (ctrl+c) server, all sent data is printing on client's terminal.
How to fix code to get real-time connection?

**server.py**

```
import eventlet
import socketio
import time


sio = socketio.Server()
app = socketio.WSGIApp(sio)

@sio.event
def connect(sid, environ):
    print('connect ', sid)
    my_message(sid, "Client connected")
    # f(sid)


@sio.event
def my_message(sid, data):
    sio.send(data)
    print('Send message ', data)


@sio.event
def disconnect(sid):
    print('disconnect ', sid)


@sio.on('subscribe_to_data')
def subscribe(sid, data):
    counter = 0
    while True:
        sio.send(counter)
        print('Send message from server ', counter)
        counter += 1
        # my_message(sid, i)
        time.sleep(1)

eventlet.wsgi.server(eventlet.listen(('', 5000)), app)
```

**client.py**

```
import socketio

sio = socketio.Client()


@sio.event
def connect():
    print('connection established')
    sio.emit('subscribe_to_data', "I want to subscribe")


@sio.event
def message(data):
    print('message received with ', data)
    

@sio.event
def disconnect():
    print('disconnected from server')


sio.connect('http://localhost:5000')
sio.wait()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better implementation will be to maintain a list of connected clients and do something like

```py
while sid in CONNECTED_CLIENTS:
    pass
```

Also instead of `time.sleep()` use `sio.sleep()`